# How to get output without runing AVD in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have a ArrayList with some data and want print data of that in logcat or console and test output, if it will work then use AVD and show data in a ListView. for first time i dont want to use AVD. but when i want run app it open AVD and take more time.

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db.addContacts(new Contacts(0, "name1", "00000"));
    db.addContacts(new Contacts(1, "name2", "11111"));
    db.addContacts(new Contacts(2, "name3", "22222"));

    List<Contacts> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    for ( Contacts c: contacts) {
        text = "ID: " + c.getId() + ",Name: " + c.getName() + ", Phone Number: " + c.getPhone_number() + "\n";
        system.out.print(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) for that. If you do not plan to release your code on Android at all, you can create a usual Java Application using IntelliJ Idea. IntelliJ is basically the same as Android Studio but not limited to Android development.

Comment: I want to test it every time I edit the code if it's suitable, then I'll run in AVD. Because AVD takes a lot of time to run.

Comment: That's what unit tests are for. Click the link in my answer to learn more. Also, consider marking my answer as the solution if it worked for you.